# Electron density in DFT (*ρ*(r)) and probability density (wave function squared)

Tags: electrons, probability, density, density-functional-theory

Are the electron density in density functional theory, *ρ*(r), and probability density, defined as wave function squared, the same quantities?

Comment: 1 year is long to not get an answer with upvotes, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hartree approximation the  electron density is computed as the sum of the probability densities of the occupied orbitals:

$$\rho=\sum_{j\;\mathrm{occupied}} \Psi_j(\vec{r})^*\Psi_j(\vec{r})$$

Source: Electronic Structure of Materials, A. Sutton